# Giving QML a const pointer to a const object rather than a non-const object?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a project using QML in which QML has has an object of type `Foo`. I want to change it so that QML has an object of type `const Foo`. How do I do this? I have QML calling a C++ function that was working and took a `Foo*`. I changed it to take a `const Foo*` (as it logically should), but I get a runtime error on the QML line that calls it, saying "`Error: Unknown method parameter type: const Foo*`".

I tried changing

```
qmlRegisterType<Foo>("FooLib", 1, 0, "Foo");
```

to

```
qmlRegisterType<const Foo>("FooLib", 1, 0, "Foo");
```

but to no avail. I then tried doing

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Foo>("FooLib", 1, 0, "Foo", "Can't create one");
```

and replacing my QML `FooLib.Foo {}` with a call to a factory method I created that returns a `Foo*`. Same runtime error.

I tried making my factory return a `const Foo*`. That made progress. That makes it not crash. However, I get a runtime error in QML like "`TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined`" where it's trying to access a `Q_PROPERTY` of `Foo`. The property only has a `READ` and that member function is `const`. The error about `undefined` makes me think maybe QML doesn't know that a `const Foo` is the same as a `Foo` when it comes to `const` `Q_PROPERTY`s, or that it's getting `Foo*`s from other functions and doesn't know that those can be converted to `const Foo*`s.

Is that right? Is QML unable to automatically convert `Foo*` to `const Foo*`? How am I supposed to write const-correct code?

Comment: `qmlRegisterType` registers an Item which could be created in QML, no further action is required. What is `REGISTER_QT_META_TYPE` here? `const` is a C++ keyword and make no sense in QML. To communicate with QML you have `Q_INVOKABLE` macro and `Q_PROPERTY`. Use one of them to access data. You can specify `CONSTANT` attribute for `Q_PROPERTY` to make it constant.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like `REGISTER_QT_META_TYPE` is a macro from a former colleague for `qRegisterMetaType<T>(#T)`. I’ll reassess and edit the post to reflect a saner question. Thanks.